# Do something after a new cell is created

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have been trying to wrap my head around doing this, but I can't seem to find an elegant way. I tried to inject a code to make the `UITextView` in my custom `UITableViewCell` become first responder just after a cell is created.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            // store some of the cell information
            _newlyCreatedCell = @{@"path": newIndexPath, @"age":[NSDate date],@"cell":(CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath]};

           [[(CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row-1 inSection:0]] textLabel] becomeFirstResponder];

            // highlight cell
            [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;
}
```

I got this rough code, but it doesn't seem to be the best method or the working one. I had this rough and faulty idea of storing the newly created cell's information in a `NSDictionary`. Very bad. Anyways then I started to fiddle with changing the `newIndexPath` value, because it didn't return the `NSIndexPath` for the newly created cell (probably written in the Apple documentation somewhere...). So I set the value to `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row-1 inSection:0]`, expecting of course that it would return the correct value. But that returned `(null)`. Nothing happened.

Does anybody know a better and probably simpler way to execute a bunch of code right when a new cell is created?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returning `nil` for a correct (assuming it is) index path is a huge issue alone.

Comment: How are you creating your new cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried it by myself, but `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

may be helpful here. As stated in the docs:

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color.

There may be a problem if you insert more than one cell at a time. But you use NSFetchedResultsController, which sorts the data used to populate the cells, so maybe you can figure out which cell is the 'last one'.

Comment: I think he's creating the cells with Core Data and that's why he's not using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused as to why you are trying to access the cell information before it's created.  Shouldn't you be trying to make the cell's text label be first responder after it's created?  Something like:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        //Then do
       [[(CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:0]] textLabel] becomeFirstResponder];

        break;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I am trying to access the cell information after it's created, not before. The problem with your suggestion is that it won't return the indexPath for the cell that's just been created. Instead it will return the one after it. That's why I tried `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row-1 inSection:0]]`. But that wouldn't work.

Comment: Hmmm... that's strange.  NSLog(@"%i", newIndexPath.row); Should give you the correct indexPath. It may have something do with how your fetching the objects that are used for the creation of the Cell's.  Are you expecting the new cell row to be added at the end of the section?  Like if you already had rows 0-5 are you expecting the new cell to be 6?

Comment: My objects are sorted by date, so I set `ascending: NO`. So to answer your question, no I wouldn't expect it to. Here is the full code: `    self.fetchedResultsController = [Object MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"dateScheduled" ascending:NO withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"dateGroup" delegate:self inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread]];`